# Contain script function within body of html

Tags: c#, html

I have written a database connection -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head2" runat="server">
<title>SQL Authentication</title>
<h1>title</h1>
</head>
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.table", cn);
        ...etc...
        ...etc...
</script>
<html>
```

How can I use this function within the html of a web page, as currently it is taking all the results from the database, and it is filling the whole page, and any modifications I make to the html e.g. `<h1>Title</h1>` are coming out underneath the table of database results?

Comment: Start here - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of displaying data in WebForms is with data bound controls such as the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx). There are numerous tutorials on how to do this. Start with the ones on http://asp.net.

[ASP.NET Data Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague so perhaps enhance it a bit more but maybe this will help:

Add `if (!IsPostBask() {}` in your Page_Load event to prevent the SQL being executed every page load.

I would also recommend you have a code behind file if using ASP.Net Webforms

Answer (score 1):

You can only 'use' this by doing a Postback to the server.

`Page_Load()` is a server-side event. So much better to place it (leave it) in the code behind file.